# Use gulp src list in template

Tags: handlebars.js, gulp

Let's say that I build all my handlebar templates into a build folder as follows:

```
gulp.src('./source/pages/**/*.hbs')
  .pipe(plugins.consolidate('handlebars', config))
  .pipe(plugins.extReplace('.html'))
  .pipe(gulp.dest('./build'))
  .pipe(/* ??? */)
```

In the last `pipe(/* ??? */)`, I would like to create an `index.html` file with a list of links to `build/**/*.html` using the following template:

```
<ul>
{{#each files}}
  <li>
    <a href="{{this}}">{{this}}</a>
  </li>
{{/each}}
</ul>
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I would use an approach like gulp-concat, but create a list of file paths instead of buffering the contents: https://github.com/wearefractal/gulp-concat/blob/master/index.js

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to use [the `gulp-wrap` plugin](https://www.npmjs.org/package/gulp-wrap/) to solve this:

```js
.pipe(wrap('  <li>\n    <a href="<%= file.path %>"><%= file.path %></a>\n  </li>'))
.pipe(concat('index.html'))
.pipe(wrap('<ul>\n<%= contents %>\n</ul>'))
```

I think this might be too hackish, but it might work.  The biggest issue I see is that `file.path` probably doesn't link the way you want it to.